# How to use WordPress 3.8 back-end CSS in front-end?

Tags: css, front-end

How to use WordPress 3.8 back-end CSS in front-end?

I want to use the back-end button CSS, button icons CSS etc. onto the front-end side. Is there any way, I can just call the CSS class in front-end to use them directly?

Comment: what you want to do? plz explain your question with more details

Comment: i want like back-end button css , like button icons ..... apply on front-end side button or anything like css there by use class of back-end .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're asking how to include the admin styles in your front end theme?  If so, you simply need to either enqueue 'wp-admin' on it's own or list it as a dependency for your theme/plugin stylesheet.  Here are examples of both methods:

By itself:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-admin' );
```

As a dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-styles', 'path-to-my-css.css', array( 'wp-admin' ), '1.0.0' );
```

There are also several individual parts of the admin css that can be enqueued separately as well:

```
'dashicons'
'admin-bar'
'thickbox'
'wp-admin'
'buttons'
'colors'
```

Although enqueueing any of these individually may have less than ideal results as I don't believe they are listed as dependent on eachother.